# How to print a JS function into HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom-events

I have a function that shows the repeated letters in an object. I want to display {J: 1, O: 1, N: 2, A: 1} in an HTML file when I click a button.

Javascript:

```
let button = document.getElementById("button");
button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
   countLetters();
});
function countLetters() {
   let name = ["J", "O", "N", "N", "A"];
   let newObj = {};
   name.map(function (letters) {
   newObj[letters] = (newObj[letters] || 0) + 1;
   });
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
   <button id="button">Click me</button>
   <script src="/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify(newObj, null, 2)` gives you a string that's passably readable, and you can then insert into some html element's text node or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a div Element by

```
document.createElement("div");
```

Then you can create a textNode with your object as string by

```
document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(newObj));
```

Append your text node to your new created div element and then your div element to the documents body.

```
div.appendChild(textN);
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

```js
let button = document.getElementById("button");
button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  countLetters();
});

function countLetters() {
  let name = ["J", "O", "N", "N", "A"];
  let newObj = {};
  name.map(function(letters) {
    newObj[letters] = (newObj[letters] || 0) + 1;
  });
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  const textN = document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(newObj));
  div.appendChild(textN);
  document.body.appendChild(div);

}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <button id="button">Click me</button>
  <script src="/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a `div` or a `paragraph` in your HTML with the id attribute set to `divID`.
Then access it in the following way:

```
var div = document.getElementById('divID');

div.innerHTML += 'Extra stuff';
```